# Cocoapods Xcode Embedded Framework transitive dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

[image]

I have an app project 'Test' and a cocoa touch framework 'TestFramework' as shown on the above image. How can I use Cocoapods to declare dependency for my TestFramework, and when I embedded the 'TestFramework' into my 'Test' project, my 'Test' will be able to use the depedency in my 'TestFramework'

For example:

'TestFramework' dependency:
AFNetworking

'Test' dependency:
MBProgressHUD

After 'Test' embedded 'TestFramework', the dependency of 'Test':
MBProgressHUD
AFNetworking

In maven, I am able to declare dependency for modules in its own pom.xml, and I can set the module A to depend on module B dependency by using 
How can I achieve this with cocoapods

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a podspec file for your framework (follow these guides https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/index.html), including the dependency:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    ...

    s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
end
```

And then import your framework form your app's Podfile:

```
pod 'MyFramework'
```

This should solve transitive dependencies without problem